# How to route with no subdomain

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hi I've a question about how to enable the routing I want. My app is at appspot and the domain is hosted via google apps where it also was bought. When making the call mydomain.com/li I come to www.mydomain.com where more appropriate would be www.mydomain.com/li

The actual usage is http://koolbusiness.com/li and http://www.koolbusiness.com/li where you can see they behave differently. Can you help me solve the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is down to your domain registrar - they're the ones issuing the 302 redirects for the naked domain. If they don't provide the service you need, you may want to point your DNS elsewhere, such as [zoneedit](http://www.zoneedit.com/), or another provider who preserves the path correctly.